# How to connect with elasticache using redis in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis, amazon-elasticache

I have created a elasticache redis cluster in aws.
Now I have endpoint(url + port)

Url looks "myredis.abc.xyz.cache.amazonaws.com" and port 6379

Now I want to store `Key:Value` pair in it, like we store in native Redis (`redis.set, redis.get`)

How to write nodejs code for it, I don't know. I searched a lot but didn't find any right resource.

Anyone can help me in this?

I tried following code but didn't work

```
    ElastiCacheClient,
    AddTagsToResourceCommand,
  } = require("@aws-sdk/client-elasticache");
  const conf = {
    host: "myredis.abc.xyz.cache.amazonaws.com",
    port: 6379,
    region: "us-east-1",
  };
  const client = new ElastiCacheClient(conf);
  const param = { manoj: "kumawat" };
  const command = new AddTagsToResourceCommand(param);
  const data = await client.send(command);
  console.log(data);
```

Comment: You may try this: https://github.com/cloud-gov/aws-redis-example/blob/main/node/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to an Elasticache Redis clusture using the Redis module as shown on this code

```
//load the redis module
const redis = require('redis');

//self invoking function to await the connection
(async () => {

//crete the client 
const client = redis.createClient({
    url: 'redis://my-demo-redis2-001.ukmr3w.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379'
  });

//handle the error
client.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));

//on connect, report the connection
client.on('connect', () => console.log('Redis Client Connected'));

//connect to the redis server
await client.connect();

//set the key value pair
await client.set('key', 'value123');

//get the value for the key
const value = await client.get('key');

//log the value
console.log('value', value);

//disconnect from the redis server
await client.disconnect();


})();
```